# Number of ways to put $m$ balls in $N$ bins with exactly one empty bin

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, balls-in-bins

> There are $N$ bins labelled $1,...,N$ and $m$ balls labelled $1,...,m$. How many ways are there of placing the $m$ balls into the $N$ bins (each bin can hold an arbitrary number of balls, and can be empty) if there must be exactly one empty bin?

I know in general, to put $m$ balls in $N$ bins, we can use the stars-and-bars principle; however in the case of one (or general $k$) empty bins how do we modify the stars-and-bars approach, or do we use a completely different method? (I've looked at the related questions and found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2322858/balls-in-bins-probability-that-exactly-two-bins-are-empty) but looks to be for a very specific case of $N+1$ balls.)

Comment: Are the balls distinct or indistinguishable?  In either case, choose which bin will be empty and distribute the balls to the remaining bins so that none of those bins are empty.  Counting such distributions is easier if the balls are identical.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig sadly they are labelled and distinguishable!

Answer (score 2):

One definition of the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $S(n,k)$ is the number of ways to put $n$ labelled balls in $k$ unlabelled bins with no bin empty. Thus the answer to your problem is the product of

- choosing which bins are empty: $\binom nk$
- putting the balls in the "nonempty" bins: $S(m,n-k)$
- permuting the nonempty bins (thus accounting for the bins being labelled): $(n-k)!$

This gives $\frac{n!}{k!}S(m,n-k)$.